# Making the configuration available to all classes

Tags: java, oop, singleton

I'm writing a small web server, and it takes a configuration file with all sorts of different options: how many threads to run, which class deals which each file extension, which file to display by default and so on and so forth. To represent this, I'm parsing the config file into a `Configuration` object which contains all these settings, and the main class holds this object.
However, the config data is required on almost every level of the server - classes within classes within classes...

My question is, what is the best practice to use here? Should I give the config as a parameter for many many classes and pass it back and forth? Should I make it a singleton? Is there another solution I don't see?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)!  Guice is a dependency-injection framework which effectively replaces your use of the new keyword.  You define your object bindings in a Module like this:

```
bind(Configuration.class).to(MySpecificConfiguration.class);
bind(WebServer.class).to(MySpecificWebServerImplementation.class);
```

And then, instead of newing up `WebServer` directly, you just ask Guice to do it for you:

```
WebServer ws = Guice.createInjector(yourModule).getInstance(WebServer.class);
```

Which will magically create `MySpecificWebServerImplementation` for you.  If `MySpecificWebServerImplementation` is defined as follows:

```
public class MySpecificWebServerImplementation {
    @Inject 
    public MySpecificWebServerImplementation(Configuration configuration) {
    }
}
```

Then `MySpecificWebServerImplementation` will automatically get given the configuration and you don't have to worry about passing it around.

Comment: +1 for this solution, it is the somewhat more modern DI approach compared to the old-school Singleton pattern

Answer (score 2):

Passing an instance of `Configuration` around adds a lot of unnecessary clutter to your code. A Singleton is a good idea or add some sort of *Manager* class that provides all those shared resources, like configuration data.

If you go for singleton, consider implementing the enum pattern:

```
public enum Config{ DATA;

   private int value1;
   private int value2;
   private int value3;
   public load(File configFile) {
     // some magic to store the values
   }
   public int getValue1() {return value1;}
   public int getValue2() {return value2;}
   public int getValue3() {return value3;}
}
```

You can use it everywhere in your code:

```
int property = Config.DATA.getValue1();
```

Comment: Tying the file to each class and making it effectively much harder to test. Use enums as intended to define constants, but forgo the singleton. Logging class being the exception. Config object is the perfect example of a Dependency Injection solution.

Answer (score 2):

Although `Singletons` are no longer favored by many professionals for various reasons - I think there is still a good use case to use a Ssingleton`.

However - ask yourself if the webserver's requirements really require a single common configuration for all aspects of the server. And if yes - how likely are they to change soon?
For example - lets say your server hosts 3 web sites. And now you are asked to put bandwidth limitations on one of them - how will you configure this?

I really favor a good singleton - although you have to mind the whole thread-safety issue when initializing it in a multi-threaded environment (Although it sounds like you won't have this problem as you won't have multiple threads before initializing it.

Keep in mind that singletons live within a `ClassLoader` and if you have multiple `ClassLoader`s (e.g. for each `.war` you load) you will have multiple copies of this "`Singleton`".

Consider all the aspects of your server, and if it is really simple - A `Singleton` will save you a lot of headache - and will make the code much more maintainable and readable.
As mentioned already in one or two of the answers - dependency injection is a good alternative to `Singleton`s - they help you make your JUnits easier.

One note about JUnit, I understand (didn't try it yet) that `Mockit` can allow you to replace an actual implementation during a test run, so you can still create different JUnit test cases for different scenarios without modifying your `Singleton` to be testable.

Comment: could you elaborate on your statement that "Singletons are no longer favored by many professionals for various reasons"? I'm not sure I follow you...

Comment: @stupahsmaht - Many developers are referring to a `Singleton` as an `antipattern`, meaning something you should not do. If you google "singleton antipattern" you can find many references to it in many blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Making it a singleton seems like a reasonable solution. I think it would be a mistake to pass the config around as a parameter to other other classes constructors or method calls as this will tend to pollute the method arguments and make them unnecessarily complex.

If you do decide to make a singleton, then I'd recommend devising a mechanism whereby you can inject new instances of the config into the singleton class so that the singleton doesn't make your unit tests very hard to run.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in Java, I would place all the configuration in [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) and then either use the [Application Context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) to lookup the settings or simply inject them into your beans.  Spring excels at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

We have your properties set as system properties. These are accessed by a `SystemProperties` class. 
This class is `final` with a private constructor, the properties are accessed via static methods only, so it is technically a Singleton. It is itself contained in a commons.jar every other project is depending on.

So there is no need to pass anything around as the settings are available directly where you need them.

Comment: This can break as soon as more than a single webapp is installed on the server.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla - surely. It can even break on it's own, if somebody sets a property to a wrong value. The only security one has are rather long and specific property names. There are many kinds of properties in our application and the system property approach is applied to the most dynamic ones. Then there are properties deployed as bound XML, some properties in the Manifest and also some propoerties hardcoded in final classes as public static memebers. And IMHO there are valid reasons to use each of the approaches. Just not for everything

Answer (score 0):

I definitively would make the configuration holder class a Singleton! I's the classical use case for a Singleton instance.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration not, but It's good to have one singleton object `ServerManager`. Too many globally accessible objects are are little bit confusing. Configuration should by owned by "component":

```
ServerManager.getServerManager.getConfigurationComponent(Configuration.class);
```

ServerManager should create and read configuration object at start time. Save and close it before leaving.

If you use it more than once in any class store it as private final field.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this a lot. I do multiple installations of products, and they are not always in the same place. However the installation, integration, and implementation of the product is usually the same. So in order to compensate for this, I write a config properties class, that looks at a config.properties file. You would go in and modify the properties file first to the locations, values, etc... of what you need before hand. Then compile the class with the config class, and carry that through with the application.

Example below. config.properties file

```
import_dir=c:\\temp\\test\\import
export_dir=c:\\temp\\test\\export
system_dir=c:\\temp\\test\\system
username=mainman
role=admin
domain=
server=
hostname=
```

etc...

I then created a class inside of my class.

```
public static class Config {

    private static Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
    static {
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            defaultProps.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String getProperty(String key) {
        return defaultProps.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

I am sure you could also create a stand alone class, but this works as well.

Then inside of my method, or in the main class I get the values I need and assign them to whatever I need. I can then pass them to the corresponding method that needs them.

```
domain = Config.getProperty("domain");
server = Config.getProperty("server");
hostname = Config.getProperty("hostname");
```

It is pretty cool!

I also use this on multiple OS's.